# SQL - Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am rather new with `SQL` and I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't do what I'm trying here. I'm trying get the least number of free seats in a package-trip, and group them by the package ID.

The first of the subqueries work, but the second is the one I can't figure out. It says

*Unkown column SuperPaket in 'where clause'*.

```
select Paket.PaketID as "SuperPaket", Beskrivning, Resa.AvgångStad, Resa.AvgångTid, Resa.AvgångDatum,

    (select AnkomstTid from Resa where Resa.ResID in 
        (select ResID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = SuperPaket and Ordningsnr =
            (select max(Ordningsnr) from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = SuperPaket))) "AnkomstTid",

        (select min(LedigaPlatser) from
            (select sum(AntalPlatser - Count) "LedigaPlatser", ResID from(
                select Bokning.ResID, AntalPlatser, sum(Bokning.AntalBiljetter) as Count from 
                    (Resa inner join Bokning on Resa.ResID = Bokning.ResID) where Bokning.ResID in
                        (select PaketResa.ResID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = SuperPaket)
                group by Bokning.ResID order by Count desc)
            as CountTable group by ResID) 
        as T) "LedigaPlatser"

    from ((Paket inner join PaketResa on Paket.PaketID = PaketResa.PaketID) inner join Resa on PaketResa.ResID = Resa.ResID) group by Paket.PaketID;
```

Why does this work for the first subquery but not the second one?

---

Update..
The error seems to appear when I put a "sub-subquery" in a from clause. I don't know how to rewrite the problematic query to fix this problem though, and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks..

Comment: that looks very complicated, and the swedish column names don't really help ...

Comment: Do you have a column called "SuperPaket" in the actual tables (not just as a label on the outermost select statement)?

Comment: I suggest you to show table structure, sample data and desired result. Your query is way to complicated and bad formatted/written too, no table aliases and so on

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using MySQL, and I have the following tables; http://pastebin.com/BkGUkrbJ

That's the relevant ones. I don't have the column 'SuperPaket', that's an Alias for Paket.PaketID in the first select..

Comment: are you sure, it's working for first subquery?

Comment: i don't think you need "" for "SuperPaket" try doing paket.paketID as SuperPaket

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it works on the first one. I have more subqueries than these two that use SuperPaket or Paket.PaketID and they work fine.. Typing as SuperPaket doesn't work either :(

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson I think, **Level** of `subquery` also could be a problem. What I mean is your first subquery is **4th subquery to the alias** while second one is 5th. Try checking if this is the case.

Comment: Im sorry Drt, I don't know what you are talking about really. What should I do and how would I do it?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson remove `select Bokning.ResID, AntalPla.....` query and use that second subquery with `SuperPaket` at that place. See if it gives error for `SuperPaket`.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson With level I meant query inside query. So the second one with `SuperPaket` is 5th to main. While the 1st one with `SuperPaket` is 4th to main query. It might be possible that alias is supportted only till 4th level.

Comment: Sorry. Not `select Bokning.ResID, AntalPla.....` instead consider `select sum(AntalPlatser - Count)` in above comment. Also 6th not 5th

Comment: I removed the `sum(AntalPlatser-Count)` query, and change the first to `select Bokning.ResID` and keeping SuperPaket in the innermost one. Still getting unknown column :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18338/discussion-between-drt-and-christopher-carlsson)

Comment: Anyone? Still haven't got it working..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use **column alias** in a `where` clause in `mysql` and `oracle`

[From mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.
>
> You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to
>   refer to the column:

I have no idea about `sql server`

**Added :**
Your subquery probably not getting `Paket.PaketId`. 
Try modifying `from` clause of most outer query by adding

```
(select Paket.PaketID as "SuperPaket" from Paket)
```

as below

```
from (
      (Paket inner join PaketResa on Paket.PaketID = PaketResa.PaketID)   
inner join Resa on PaketResa.ResID = Resa.ResID),
      (select Paket.PaketID as "SuperPaket" from Paket)
group by Paket.PaketID;
```

Also remove alias from first `select` and just say `select SuperPaket`

Comment: I will try rewriting it using having instad, I'll report back.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlsson As `Paket.PaketID` also not working, I guess it's not able to find column `PaketID`

Comment: Changed to code in edit, now getting `error 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`. If I add `..."SuperPaket" from Paket) as TestTable` it still says `Unknown column`..

Comment: In that case, you will have to use `TestTable.SuperPaket`. Also have you tried my comment on subquery levels that could be a reason.

Answer (score -1):

your column is Paket.PaketID not "SuperPaket" so use Paket.PaketID wherever you used superpaket

```
select Paket.PaketID as "SuperPaket", Beskrivning, Resa.AvgångStad, 
        Resa.AvgångTid, Resa.AvgångDatum,

(select AnkomstTid from Resa where Resa.ResID in 
    (select ResID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = Paket.PaketID and Ordningsnr =
        (select max(Ordningsnr) from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = Paket.PaketID))) "AnkomstTid",

    (select min(LedigaPlatser) from
        (select sum(AntalPlatser - Count) "LedigaPlatser", ResID from(
            select Bokning.ResID, AntalPlatser, sum(Bokning.AntalBiljetter) as Count from 
                (Resa inner join Bokning on Resa.ResID = Bokning.ResID) where Bokning.ResID in
                    (select PaketResa.ResID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = Paket.PaketID)
            group by Bokning.ResID order by Count desc)
        as CountTable group by ResID) 
    as T) "LedigaPlatser"

from ((Paket inner join PaketResa on Paket.PaketID = PaketResa.PaketID) inner join Resa on PaketResa.ResID = Resa.ResID) group by Paket.PaketID;
```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?